# How to reference an aggregate function in the where clause

Tags: sql-server

My class is using MS SQL-Server right now, and we're playing around with queries. I'm stuck on one of them.
The question is: Show the requested information for only those investigators whose portion of the salary from the awards exceeds $10,000. Order the results in descending order of the last name.

Here's the code I have so far:

```sql
SELECT Funding.PIN, Fname, Lname, SUM (([%Salary]/100)*Salary) AS TotalSalary
FROM Funding, Investigator
WHERE Funding.PIN = Investigator.PIN
AND 10000 < (SELECT SUM (([%Salary]/100)*Salary)
             FROM Funding, Investigator)
GROUP BY Funding.PIN, Fname, Lname
ORDER BY Lname DESC;
```

Whenever I run it, it's showing all the investigators and their salaries even if they're under $10,000. Anyone how to properly execute this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE`

- To filter records : **Where Clause**
- To filter groups  : **Having Clause**

Try something like this

```
SELECT Funding.PIN, Fname, Lname, SUM (([%Salary]/100)*Salary) AS TotalSalary
FROM Funding 
INNER JOIN Investigator
WHERE Funding.PIN = Investigator.PIN
GROUP BY Funding.PIN, Fname, Lname
having SUM (([%Salary]/100)*Salary)> 10000
ORDER BY Lname DESC;
```

Comment: I just tried it and it worked perfectly! Makes sense now. Thank you!!

Comment: You can also use aliases in the HAVING clause, to prevent code duplication: `having TotalSalary > 10000`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - That may not work in all the database engines